# Remove HTML Tag using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'd like to remove `<font>` tags from my html and am trying to use `replaceChild` to do so, but it doesn't seem to work properly.  Can anyone catch what might be wrong?

```
$html = '<html><body><br><font class="heading2">Limited Size and Resources</font><p><br><strong>Q: When can a member use the limited size and resources exception?</strong></p></body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$font_tags = $dom->GetElementsByTagName('font');

foreach($font_tags as $font_tag) {
  foreach($font_tag as $child) {
    $child->replaceChild($child->nodeValue, $font_tag);
  }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

From what I understand, `$font_tags` is a `DOMNodeList`, so I need to iterate through it twice in order to use the `DOMNode::replaceChild` function.  I then want to replace the current value with just the content inside of the tags.  However, when I output the $html nothing changes.  Any ideas what could be wrong?

[Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18513fea5cb760721e53dfe92d87b8cf24f01d69) is a PHP Sandbox to test the code.

Comment: my php is non existant, but you're echo'ing $html which was the original string, not the modified $dom.

Comment: You do need to change `echo $html;` to `echo $dom->saveHTML();` but it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Woops... silly me.  Changing it to echo `$dom->saveHTML();` still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll put my remarks inline

```
$html = '<html><body><br><font class="heading2">Limited Size and Resources</font><p><br><strong>Q: When can a member use the limited size and resources exception?</strong></p></body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$font_tags = $dom->GetElementsByTagName('font');

/* You only need one loop, as it is iterating your collection 
   You would only need a second loop if each font tag had children of their own
*/
foreach($font_tags as $font_tag) {
  /* replaceChild replaces children of the node being called
     So, to replace the font tag, call the function on its parent
     $prent will be that reference
  */
  $prent = $font_tag->parentNode;
   /* You can't insert arbitrary text, you have to create a textNode
      That textNode must also be a member of your document
   */
  $prent->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode($font_tag->nodeValue), $font_tag);

}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[Updated Sandbox:  Hopefully I understood your requirements correctly](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/351510b60de6b7a2e0c8bbd3ea3af38d38e18b03)

Comment: Man!  I was so close to this solution before I made a few steps back.  I had `$font_tag->parentNode->replaceChild($font_tag->nodeValue, $font_tag);` but kept getting the error 'Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::replaceChild() must be an instance of DOMNode' which is why I thought I had to iterate twice.  In this case, I should have just added `createTextNode`...

Comment: It's not hard to get close to a real answer then wind up 10 miles away.  So I take it this did what you were looking for?

Comment: Still testing, but I will definitely mark as correct if it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### First, let us find out what wasn't working in your code.

1. `foreach($font_tag as $child)` wasn't even iterating once as `$font_tag` is a single 'font' tag element from `font_tags` array, and not an array itself.
2. `$child->replaceChild($child->nodeValue, $font_tag);` - A child node can't replace its parent (`$font_tag`), but the reverse is possible.
   As replaceChild is a method of the parent node to replace its child.
   For more details check the [PHP: DOMNode::replaceChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) documentation, or the point 2 below my code.
3. `echo $html` will output the `$html` string, but not the updated `$dom` object that we are modifying.

---

#### This would work -

```
$html = '<html><body><br><font class="heading2">Limited Size and Resources</font><p><br><strong>Q: When can a member use the limited size and resources exception?</strong></p></body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$font_tags = $dom->GetElementsByTagName('font');

foreach($font_tags as $font_tag)
{
    $new_node = $dom->createTextNode($font_tag->nodeValue);
    $font_tag->parentNode->replaceChild($new_node, $font_tag);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

1. I am creating a `$new_node` directly in the `$dom`, so the node is live in the DOMDocument and not any local variable.
2. To replace the child object `$font_tag`, we have to first traverse to the parent node using the `parentNode` method.
3. Finally, we are printing out the modified `$dom` using `saveHTML` method, which will [convert the DOMDocument into a HTML String](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

Answer (score 0):

#### Remove a specific span tag from HTML while preserving/keeping the inside content using PHP and DOMDocument

```php
<?php

$content = '<span style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 12pt;"><div>asdf</div><span>TWO</span>Business owners are fearful of leading. They would rather follow the leader than embrace a bold move that challenges their confidence. </span>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
// Use LIBXML for preventing output of doctype, <html>, and <body> tags
$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//span[@style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 12pt;"]') as $span) {

    // Move all span tag content to its parent node just before it.
    while ($span->hasChildNodes()) {
        $child = $span->removeChild($span->firstChild);
        $span->parentNode->insertBefore($child, $span);
    }

    // Remove the span tag.
    $span->parentNode->removeChild($span);
}

// Get the final HTML with span tags stripped
$output = $dom->saveHTML();

print_r($output);
```